# Matplotlib imshow with circular units

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a smallish matrix and I want to do `imshow` with it with `interpolation='nearest'`. But this makes discrete square blocks. Is it possible to make the blocks circular and also control the size of the block?

Comment: it would be nice if you could post a working sample of your code that is using `interpolation='nearest'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `imshow` plots are designed to fill the space of the plots ("im" is short for image and images fill the plot space), which is inconsistent with your desire to plot circles.

A [scatter plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) in a grid would be an easy route to a grid of circle.  Here's an example:

[image]

```
from pylab import *

N = 10
r0 = 0.6
x = linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = linspace(0, 1, 10)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
size = rand(N,N)
c = size
scatter(X,Y,s=700*size, marker='o', c=c)

show()
```

You can get more control if you use plotting primitives.  Two such examples from the matplolib gallery are [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_collection.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/specialty_plots/hinton_demo.html).